# Mapping ports of the host machine to the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

is that right in my docker_compose.yml i would like to mapped port 29944 of the host to 9944 of the container, 30333 to 30333 and 29933 to 9933  would like to map some ports in my docker_compose.yml ?

```
    ports:
  - "29944:9944"
  - "30333:30333"
  - "29933:9933"
expose:
  - "9944"
  - "30333"
  - "9933"
```

Thanks

Comment: `expose:` does pretty much nothing and I'd recommend just entirely deleting that block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the format is right.

- "HostPort:ContainerPort"

expose:

- "ContainerPort"

Also another thing, the file name will be docker-compose.yml not docker_compose.yml